# Silverlight Store Data Locally

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I'm using silverlight 3. I'd like to know if silverlight is capable of storing libraries, graphics and other objects on the local machine?

For example. I have a LUA script, some textures, new libraries that the application will call to and also parses the LUA script. Is it possible for me to just re-compile the main silverlight Application and upload that alone, so when the client reloads the app, the stored dll, scripts and tectures are not re-downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly. You can use the browser cache to keep bits and pieces locally, though (eg, multiple xap files as resources- look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315412.aspx) for a starting point).